# Relacionamento intermediário entre duas tabelas Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, relacionamento

Boa noite eu tenho as seguintes tabelas na minha aplicação.

```
Doacao 
-id
-nome
-doador_id

Instituicao
-id
-nome

Doador
-id
-nome
```

> Preciso realizar o relacionamento, em uma **terceira tabela** entre as **Doações** e **Instituições** que estão interessadas na doação, que ao meu ver ficaria na seguinte arquitetura.

```
id doacao_id  instituicao_id
1   20          5
2   20          6
3   25          7
```

> **PS**: Esta tabela vai ser somente para o doador (dono da doação) ver quais instituições estão interessadas, **e ele selecionar somente uma**, os outros registros da mesma doação irão ser deletados...

como devo fazer esse relacionamento no laravel?

Answer (score 1):

Kasio, na verdade é bem simples fazer os relacionamentos no laravel, então vamos lá.

O relacionamento que você deseja e que faz todo sentido lógico para o seu problema é [Many to Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

```
N:M -> Many To Many (Muitos para Muitos)
```

Ficaria na assim :D

---

### Model - Instituicao

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Instituicao extends Model
{
    /**
     * Definindo que instituição possui várias doações.
     */
    public function doacoes()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\Doacoes', 'doacao_instituicao', 'instituicao_id', 'doacao_id');
    }
}
```

### Model - Doacao

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Doacao extends Model
{
    /**
     * Definindo que doação possui várias instituições.
     */
    public function instituicoes()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\instituicoes', 'doacao_instituicao', 'doacao_id', 'instituicao_id');
    }
}
```

Pronto agora você já finalizou o relacionamento Many to Many :D

---

No seu `Controller` você pode utilizar da seguinte maneira para consegui acessar o relacionamento

```
$instituicao = App\Instituicao::find(1);

foreach ($instituicao->doacoes as $doacao) {
    //
}
```

Ou

```
$doacoes = App\Instituicao::find(1)->doacoes()->orderBy('nome')->get();
//Lembrando que você pode fazer o inverso também :D
```

---

### Observações

O laravel segui um padrão de nomeação de tabelas e `foreign key` para os seus relacionamentos.

Para definir essa relação, são necessários três tabelas de banco de dados: `instituicoes, doacoes, e doacao_instituicao`. A `doacao_instituicao` tabela é derivada da ordem alfabética dos nomes de modelos relacionados e contém as colunas `doacao_id` e `instituicao_id`.

Comment: Será que usando o [l5-repository](https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository) não seria mais fácil pra ele?

Comment: Só para deixar como observação `l5-repositorio` é uma camada acima, ele precisa que os relacionamentos estejam corretos e isso é feito no model. @TiagoFerezin e a resposta é essa mesma.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Eu resolvi assim mesmo tive que fazer outra gambiarra para não inserir linhas repetidas exemplo.. mesmo id de doação com mesmo id de instituição...  Quanto a recuperar a relação ainda não fiz mas vai ser exibido era relação somente para o "dono" da doação............ Os estou usando o pacote i5 repository

Comment: @VirgilioNovicisso da pra ser feito no I5 repository tb

Comment: @KasioEduardo evite ficar fazendo gambiarras nos códigos, senão a manutenção fica complicada depois.